# Counting posts and trigger it

Tags: functions

I am trying to figure out how i can install a code for the counting posts. I already have a code for the posts on the website. But i want to trigger it for example if there are no posts, the text should change to no posts found or if there is just one post the text should then be: we found 1 post.

Here is the code i made in the function.php

```
function wpb_total_posts() { 
$total = wp_count_posts()->publish;
echo 'We found', "<strong>" . $total . "</strong>", 'jobs';
}
```

and this one i made in the loop

```
<div>
    <h4 class="total-posts">
    <?php wpb_total_posts(); ?>     
    </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be done with a simple `if` statement, which is beginner level PHP and does not need WordPress specific expertise. What part specifically are you struggling with? If total is more than 1 do X else if total is 1 do Y else do Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `wpb_total_posts` function like bellow:

```
function wpb_total_posts() { 
    $total = wp_count_posts()->publish;
    if($total == 1){
        echo 'We found', "<strong>" . $total . "</strong>", 'job';
    }elseif($total > 1){
        echo 'We found', "<strong>" . $total . "</strong>", 'jobs';
    }else{
        echo 'No posts found ';
    }
}
```

Here I'm first checking if total amount of post is 1 or more and handling singular/plural accordingly. Lastly if there is no post then rendering "No post found"

Comment: Sabbir, you are the best. It works. Thank you very much!

Comment: welcome :) Glad it helped you.